# Rewriting the Colding and Minicozzi's operator as an operator in the form given by Gilbarg and Trudinger

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-operators

I am trying to prove the corollary $5.15$ of [this](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v175-n2-p07-p.pdf) paper by Colding and Minicozzi on page $28$ (it is the page $782$ with respect to the numeration of the journal), which is The Eigenvalue Problem for the operator defined by Colding and Minicozzi on page $26$ (it is the page $780$ with respect to the numeration of the journal). The specific inner product which turns out the operator self-adjoint is also defined in the same page in the theorem $5.2$.

Gilbarg and Trudinger in their famous book about elliptic PDEs prove the Eigenvalue Problem for a self-adjoint operator in the form

> $$Lu = D_i(a^{ij}D_j u + b^i u) - b^i D_i u + c u,$$
>
> where $[a^{ij}]$ is symmetric.

This is on page $212$.

An important identity is

> $$\mathcal{L}v = \Delta v - \frac{1}{2} \left\langle x,\nabla v \right\rangle = e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4}} \text{div} \left( e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}} \nabla v \right)$$

on page $18$ (it is the page $772$ with respect to the numeration of the journal) of the paper. This combined with

$$\text{grad} f = \sum_{i,j} g^{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \partial_j,$$

$$\text{div} V = \sum_i V_{; i}^i = \sum_i \left\{ \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^i} + \sum_j \Gamma_{ij}^i V^j \right\}$$

and

the operator defined by Colding and Minicozzi, which I put here by convenience,

$$Lu = \Delta u + |A|^2 u + \frac{1}{2} u - \frac{1}{2} \left\langle x, \nabla u \right\rangle$$

give

$\begin{align}
L H &= e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4}} \sum_i \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}} g^{ij} \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_j} \right) + \sum_j \Gamma_{ij}^i \left( e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}} \sum_k g^{jk} \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_k} \right) \right\} + |A|^2 H - \frac{1}{2} H
\end{align}$

I thought that I need to solve the following equation

$$ \frac{\partial b^k}{\partial x_k} H = \sum_i \left\{ \sum_j \Gamma_{ij}^i \left( \sum_k g^{jk} \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_k} \right) \right\}$$

to find $b^k$ and then the Colding and Minicozzi's operator be written in the form given by Gilbarg and Trudinger, but I could not develop from here. I would like some help to rewrite the operator above as in the form given by Gilbarg and Trudinger.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please give the page references in the journal's page numbers?

Comment: Of course! I just have edited my topic.

Comment: Thanks! Are you trying to show that $L$ is self-adjoint wrt to the weighted space or do you take this as true?

Comment: If you are convinced of this, then the conclusion is an application of the standard spectral theory of compact self-adjoint operators (aka Hilbert-Schmidt theory).

Comment: I am convinced of this and realize that the lemma is only an application of the standard spectral theory of compact self-adjoint operators is not a problem. The problem is realize that $Lu = \Delta u + |A|^2 u + \frac{1}{2} u - \frac{1}{2} \left\langle x, \nabla u \right\rangle$ can be written in the form $Lu = D_i(a^{ij}D_j u + b^i u) - b^i D_i u + c u$, then the lemma follows by the standard spectral theory of compact self-adjoint operators as you said.

Comment: I was asking if you are convinced that the operator is self-adjoint. It seems that your are not convinced. To check that it is self-adjoint, you don't need to write in that form. Formula (5.4) tells you that it is self-adjoint.

Comment: I am convinced of this. This last comment yours led me to think the standard spectral theory of compact self-adjoint operators can be used to prove the eigenvalue problem for an elliptic operator in the form $Lu = a^{ij} D_{ij} u + b^i D_i u + c u$. Do you have a reference for this? I only read the eigenvalue problem for the operator $Lu = D_i(a^{ij}D_j u + b^i u) - b^i D_i u + c u$ in the Gilbarg and Trudinger's book and $Lu = - \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j}$ in the Evans' book. I thought rewrite the operator in the form given by Gilbarg and Trudinger to prove the corollary $5.15$.

Comment: If lecture notes are ok, the general theory in Section 3 of these notes should apply.

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f18/laplacenotes.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference! What is $H_0$ in the theorem $17$ of the section $3$?

Comment: Can you give me a hint to show that the Colding and Minicozzi's operator is compact? This is the only hypothesis of the theorem $17$ that I can not see directly how the Colding and Minicozzi's operator satisfies.

Comment: You need to take the resolvent of the operator, not $L$ itself. And $H_0=\{0\}$.

Comment: I did not understand. How take the resolvent of the operator $L$ helps me to show that $L$ is compact?

Comment: L is not compact. The resolvent is compact. You apply the spectral theorem to the resolvent, and then deduce spectral properties of L from there.

Comment: Look at how it is done for the Laplacian in the lecture notes.